# NTFS or EXT4 for USB drive?

Tags: 18.04, filesystem, usb-drive

I want to buy a new USB drive (WD Elements Desktop 6 TB) for my Laptop which uses Ubuntu 18.04. What file system (NTFS or Ext4) should I use?
I will use the new USB drive as backup medium.
What is the down side when I use NTFS and what is the down side when I use Ext4?

Comment: If you want it to work with both Ubuntu and Windows, NTFS works with both. Iuse NTFS.

Comment: What is HTFS? Is it a typo instead of NTFS?

Comment: Sorry. HTFS is a typo. I mean NTFS.

Answer (score 3):

If you plan to use it exclusively on Linux, stick with a Unix file system, such as XFS or EXT4.

If you need to use it cross-platform you should probably go with either NTFS or ExFAT.

Native file systems (e.g. XFS, EXT4) have better tools available for Linux, for recovery and maintenance, and probably a more complete implementation.

Comment: If you use NTFS, you must have Windows or Windows repair disk to make repairs. Almost all repairs you may need like chkdsk, defrag or or other cannot be done from Linux. And NTFS does not support Linux ownership & permissions. You lose those settings. If only data easily reset, but if any system files, just about impossible to reset, so backup to NTFS will not be valid.

Comment: @oldfred Feel free to edit that into the question if you want :)